# "(#324) Requires upload file" error while trying to upload image on facebook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, facebook-graph-api, photo

I have been trying to post an image from my js application on facebook using fb.api but get "#324 Requires file upload" error. My image source is from an URL.

I am able to login and connect to facebook but not upload image so the appId and all the connections are in place.

```
FB.api(
      "/763663567360768/photos",
      "POST",
      {
        "url": "http://sgpup.com/files/2013-07-02_00001.jpg"
      },
      function (response) {
        if (response && !response.error) {
          console.log(response);
        }
        else {
          console.log(response);
        }
      }
    );
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is no `source` parameter, there is only `url` according to the docs.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/photos/#Creating

> Use a photo that is already on the internet by publishing using the **url** parameter

**Edit: You can only publish to Pages, not to user profiles.**

Comment: I had tried that. When I update my code to 

"POST",
      {
        "url": "http://sgpup.com/files/2013-07-02_00001.jpg"
      }
I get the following error: 

"(#200) This endpoint is deprecated since the required permission publish_actions is deprecated"

Comment: Can this issue be occurring because I am trying to post the image from a "localhost" url?

Comment: well...that error message tells you what´s wrong. you cannot upload to a user profile anymore, only to a page. check out the changelog, and the api reference. i have added that information to my answer.

Comment: and of course you cannot use an image from localhost. "already on the internet" means it needs to be available in public.

Comment: Please check my updated code. Now its giving this error: 
"(#200) The permission(s) publish_actions are not available. It has been deprecated. If you want to provide a way for your app users to share content to Facebook, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead." 
I have checked https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog also but still could not figure out the issue.

Comment: i just told you about that, please read my comments again, and the edit in my answer